# Choose I use a suffix or prefix when naming variables?

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, naming

Suppose I should have a foreground and a background image, each with their own variable for width, height, and bits per pixel. Should I define my variables as `fg_width`, `fg_height`, `fg_bits_per_pixel`, `bg_width`, etc. or should I define them as `width_fg`, `height_fg`, `bits_per_pixel_fg`, `width_bg`, etc.

(Let me know if this post belongs in another stackexchange forum, I'm not sure if it belongs here)

Comment: Why don't you have some kind of data structure holding the three related values for each image?

Comment: I know that you can do that but that's not the point of the question. It's too bad I couldn't come up with a better example, but I just want to know whether naming with a prefix or suffix is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing a noun with attributes is more natural since that is how you would write it in English (although with a space inbetween), e.g. *foreground width* rather than *width foreground*. So, when choosing a variable name, first consider what it describes in the most basic sense. In your example it's a *width*, a *height* and a *ratio*. Then add prefix attributes to make the names sufficiently accurate. For a boolean variable, choose an adjective instead and prefix it with a noun phrase, e.g. *fg_width_defined*.